# get data of a user that his profile seems like: www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=0123456789

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wrote the next code:

```
var client = new FacebookClient();
string str, profile_name;

foreach (var myFriend in @Model.Friends.Data)
{
    str = myFriend.Link.ToString();
    profile_name = str.Substring(@str.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    dynamic me = client.Get(profile_name);
}
```

it passes all the links of my friends list (for example: http://www.facebook.com/mariah.carey.62), takes only the string after the last: `/` (in this case: `mariah.carey.62`), and gets the public information (gender, name, etc).

my problem is: there are few links that seems like: http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=0123456789. and then, `profile_name` is: `profile.php?id=0123456789`. assuming I success to send: client.Get("0123456789"). the graph of this user seems like:

```
"id": "0123456789",
"name": "\u05d0\u05e1\u05e0\u05ea \u05d0\u05d4\u05e8\u05d5\u05df",
"first_name": "\u05d0\u05e1\u05e0\u05ea",
"last_name": "\u05d0\u05d4\u05e8\u05d5\u05df",
"link": "https://www.facebook.com/people/\u05d0\u05e1\u05e0\u05ea-
\u05d0\u05d4\u05e8\u05d5\u05df/0123456789",
"gender": "female",
```

(the graph is found at: http://graph.facebook.com/0123456789)

how can I get understandable data of this user? the name that I got tells me nothing. maybe there is a way to decrypt it.

Comment: What is your question? The basic URL for a graph api request for a user's data is https://graph.facebook.com/`<USER ID OR USERNAME>` - it seems you know this, so i don't understand your problem

Comment: thank you for your comment. I don't know what is this name? I want his real name. the name: '\u05d0\u05e1\u05e0\u05ea \u05d0\u05d4\u05e8\u05d5\u05df' tells me nothing :/

Comment: You're not decoding the response, that name is `אסנת אהרון`

Comment: good! how can you get it?

Comment: These are Unicode characters, simply translate every \u[Number] to it's respective character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(str);
```